# Testcafe Cookie handling?

Tags: cookies, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I have a question about TestCafe usage. I have a script (fixture) with two tests inside. If the first test runs the URL and if not logged in, the script will log into the site.

BUT: the second test always logs in too. It looks like Testcafe does not recognize the cookies done in a fixture. What is the string inside the fixture or runner, to keep the set cookies?

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Ordner erstellen`
   .page `xxxx`
   .before(async ctx  => {
      ctx.clLogin = `xxxx`;
      ctx.clPassword = `xxx`;
    });
test('Create and Delete Folder1', async t => {
const testfolder = Selector('.np-folder-name[title="19233456"]')
await t
   .typeText(Selector('#email'), t.fixtureCtx.clLogin, {
      caretPos: 0
   })
   .typeText(Selector('#password'), t.fixtureCtx.clPassword, {
      caretPos: 0
   })
   .click(Selector('span').withText('Login'))
   .click(Selector('.np-top-section-tab.folder'))
await t
   .wait(2000)
   .expect(testfolder.withText('19233456').exists).notOk()

test('Create and Delete Folder2', async t => {
const testfolder = Selector('.np-folder-name[title="19233456"]')
await t
   .typeText(Selector('#email'), t.fixtureCtx.clLogin, {
      caretPos: 0
   })
   .typeText(Selector('#password'), t.fixtureCtx.clPassword, {
      caretPos: 0
   })
   .click(Selector('span').withText('Login'))
   .click(Selector('.np-top-section-tab.folder'))
await t
   .wait(2000)
   .expect(testfolder.withText('19233456').exists).notOk()
```

I also tried with the role concept from testcafe. But this is also not working well.

```
import { Selector, Role } from 'testcafe';



const admin = Role('https://bc3-channel.cliplister.com/', async t => {
    await t
        .typeText(Selector('#email'), `xxx`, {
            caretPos: 0
        })
        .typeText(Selector('#password'), `xxx`, {
            caretPos: 0
        })
        .click(Selector('span').withText('Login'))
});

fixture `Ordner erstellen`
    .page `xxx`


test('Create and Delete Folder', async t => {
    const testfolder = Selector('.np-folder-name[title="19233456"]')
    await t
        .useRole(admin)
        .navigateTo('xxx')
        .click(Selector('.np-top-section-tab.folder'))

});


test('Create and Delete Folder2', async t => {
    const testfolder = Selector('.np-folder-name[title="19233456"]')
    await t
        .navigateTo('xxx')
        .click(Selector('.np-top-section-tab.folder'))
    await t
        .wait(2000)
        .expect(testfolder.withText('19233456').exists).notOk()

});
```

Comment: Refer the solution mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975267/testcafe-the-browser-always-starts-in-clean-slate-between-the-tests-how-to-ov/57106054#57106054

Answer (score 4):

Each test in TestCafe starts with clean cookies and storages. You need to use the `useRole` call in each test if you wish to stay logged in. The `useRole` function restores cookies and storages in the second and subsequent calls that were saved on the first call. You can call the `useRole` function in the `beforeEach` hook instead of writing it manually in each test.

[User Roles](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html)

[Test Hooks](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#test-hooks)

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can resolve using Role API.

Create a Login.js page object file with your login action

```
const adminLogin = Role('https://bc3-channel.cliplister.com/', async t => {
    await t
        .typeText(Selector('#email'), `xxx`, {
            caretPos: 0
        })
        .typeText(Selector('#password'), `xxx`, {
            caretPos: 0
        })
        .click(Selector('span').withText('Login'))
});
```

Then call this const adminLogin in your fixture file as shown below : fixture.js

```
import { adminLogin } from '../page-objects/login';
fixture `Ordner erstellen`.beforeEach(async t => {
  await t.useRole(adminLogin ).navigateTo('url of the page that you want to open');
});
```