# TestCafe - The browser always starts in clean slate between the tests. How to override this so that browser remembers cache, user settings and storage

Tags: browser, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

The browser between the Tests is always open in a clean slate. The Login is remembered in my application as Authentication persists but as the browser is opened in clean slate always, I have to perform Login in Before hook of all Fixtures.
Is there some way I can open browser so that user settings, cache, local and session storage are remembered?

Answer (score 5):

TestCafe doesn't offer a way to store the page state between tests and encourages writing independent tests. However, [Roles](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html) API may meet some of your needs (refer to [this](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1770#issuecomment-335853261) comment for more details).

Answer (score 2):

This is how I resolved using Role API.

Login.js page object file

```
const loginBtn = Selector('[type="submit"]');
const password = Selector('input[placeholder="Password"]');
const userName = Selector('input[placeholder="Email"]');
export const login = Role(`http://example.com/login`, async t => {
  await t
    .typeText(userName, `abc`)
    .typeText(password, `password`)
    .click(loginBtn);
});
```

Then I called this const Login in my fixture file as shown below :
fixture.js

```
import { login } from '../page-objects/login';
fixture('Example Fixture').beforeEach(async t => {
  await t.useRole(login).navigateTo('url of the page that you want to open');
});
```